# Multiple Salesforce Web-to-Lead forms

Tags: forms, salesforce

I'm using a Salesforce Web-to-Lead form on a website i'm working on.

I want the same form to appear in 2 places, in the footer but also in a fixed position div.

Because the labels and inputs have the same ID they are conflicting with my form validation and behaving erratically.

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form key/value pairs (in HTML in general, not just SFDC of course) are submitted based on form element NAME attributes, not ID. So just remove the ID tags (or change them if they are being used by your custom validation).

Comment: Thank jkraybill — just added a prefix of footer_ to the ID and it worked.